# Random Numbers - the most common Value of $(x_1^2+y_1^2+...+x_N^2+y_N^2)/N$

Tags: probability-distributions, numerical-methods, random-variables, matlab, monte-carlo

This a check question in my Numerical Analysis course.

```
s=0.0;
N=1000000;
for n=1:N
    x=rand(1);
    y=rand(1);
    s=s+x^2+y^2;
end
display(s/N)
```

Question:
The MATLAB code above will generate an output that is usually closest to one value, which one?
The answers to choose from are $0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5, 0.6, 0.7, 0.8$ or $0.9$.

The correct answer is $0.7$.

I think that the code generates $s=x_1 ^2+y_1 ^2+ x_2^2+y_2^2+\ldots+x_N^2+y_N^2$ and then computes $\frac{s}N$ but I don't understand how to draw the conclusion that it will be $0.7$.

(This is a question from an old exam where only paper and pen is allowed.)

Comment: Since this question is about Matlab output, it appears to be off-topic here and I'm voting to close; as it stands, it is best understood by **running the code**. If it were phrased as an actual mathematics question, it might be something about the law of large numbers.

Comment: @user296602 Although this is related to mathlab it's pretty close to pseudo code and thus seems mathematical enough to me

Comment: While the question does involve a code, I believe the actual question is about the series mentioned. Therefore, it does not appear off-topic to me.

Comment: The code is is simulating $\mathbb E[X_i^2 + Y_i^2]$ which is $ \displaystyle \int_{x=0}^1 x^2 \, dx + \int_{y=0}^1 y^2 \, dy$ with these independent uniform distributions

Comment: @an4s I agree. Fundamentally a math question.

Comment: @user296602 It’s a check question from an old  exam where we only have paper and pen. So the problem is not solved by running the code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$X_i \sim \operatorname{Uni}(0,1)$, hence

$$\operatorname{Var}[X_i^2]=\frac1{12}$$

$$\mathbb{E}[X_i^2]=\operatorname{Var}[X_i^2]+\mathbb{E}(X_i)^2=\frac1{12}+\frac14=\frac13$$

I will leave $\mathbb{E}[X_i^2]+\mathbb{E}[Y_i^2]$ as an exercise.

Edit: As pointed out by Did, we could have just compute the second moment directly.

$$\mathbb{E}[X_i^2] =\int_0^1 x^2 \, dx= \frac13 $$

Comment: Passing by the variance to compute the second moment? Hmmm...

Comment: Good point, what have I done ... oh dear... should have computed that directly....